# No config DB in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, config, zabbix

I try to use mikoomi plugin for Zabbix to monitor MongoDB 3.2. Well, first it does not work for me. I went to the source to see the plugin reads info from `config` DB that should be in the mongo db. It is not there. Why?

Comment: A bit more info, please. Sharded cluster? Replica set? Number of shards, data bearing nodes?

Comment: The config database is only present on a sharded cluster.